# apply the law of total expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

I'm a little bit confused about applying the law of total expectation. Suppose $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are three random variables drawn independently from the same distribution $\mathrm{uniform}(0,1)$, which one of the following equalities is correct?

$1.$

\begin{align}
& E_2[E_3[\max\{v_2,v_3\}\mid v_1<\max\{v_2,v_3\}]] \\[8pt]
= {} &\Pr(v_2=\max\{v_2,v_3\})E_2[v_2\mid v_1 < \max\{ v_2, v_3\}, v_2=\max\{v_2,v_3\}] \\[8pt]
& {} +\Pr(v_3=\max\{v_2,v_3\})E_3[v_3\mid v_1< \max\{v_2,v_3\}, v_3=\max\{v_2,v_3\}]
\end{align}

$2.$

\begin{align}
& E_2[E_3[\max\{v_2,v_3\}\mid v_1<\max\{v_2,v_3\}]] \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(v_2=\max\{v_2,v_3\}\mid v_1<\max\{v_2,v_3\}) E_2[v_2\mid v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\},v_2 =\max\{v_2,v_3\}] \\[8pt]
& {} + \Pr(v_3 = \max\{v_2,v_3\}\mid v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\}) E_3[v_3\mid v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\}, v_3=\max\{v_2,v_3\}]
\end{align}

Comment: Your MathJax coding technique is terrible; I've cleaned it up a lot. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I thought it looks ok..but thx though

Comment: You wrote $max$ instead of $\max$.  Coding as \max not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $A\max B$, and when it is in a "displayed" setting rather than an "inline" setting affects the positions of subscripts in expressions like $\displaystyle\max_{x \in\mathcal X} f(x) \vphantom{\frac\int\int}$. And writing {$v_1,v_2$} with the {curly braces} _outside_ of MathJax results in improper spacing and mismatches in fonts and sizes, and you can't do it in a "displayed" setting.  I changed that to $\{v_1,v_2\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, notice this difference: $\Pr(v_3 = \max\{v_2,v_3\}\mid v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\})$ versus $\Pr(v_3 = \max\{v_2,v_3\}| v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\})$.  The former uses \mid and has reasonable spacing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If I wanted $\operatorname{E}(\max\{v_2,v_2\})$, I wouldn't even involve $v_1$ in that.  But maybe you're working on an exercise that requires it to be done that way. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for your advice Michael, but yea the condition exists because of previous derivations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuous random variables, the probability of a tie is immeasurably small.   So we can say: $$V_1<\max\{V_2, V_3\} \iff V_2=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\} \cup V_3=\max\{V_1, V_2, V_3\}\quad\text{a.s.}$$

Since the events in this union are disjoint (almost surely), then they partition the conditioned space:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[\max\{V_2,V_3\}\mid V_1<\max\{V_2,V_3\}]
 & = {\mathsf E[V_2\mid V_2=\max\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}]\;\mathsf P(V_2=\max\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}) + \\ \; \mathsf E[V_3\mid V_3=\max\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}]\;\mathsf P(V_3=\max\{V_1,V_2,V_3\})}\end{align}$$